# Converting special characters (é è ë) using url encoding

Tags: javascript, function, urlencode

I am making a function where user's email client just opens up with a pre-filled content (javascript).

The thing is that I am having trouble converting special characters so they are shown correctly into the email client (the content being passed by url).

I have written a function, but after doing a `console.log()` I found out that it won't even convert characters (probably because I'm trying to replace a `char` with a `string`).

```
function url_encode(item)
{
    for (i in item)
    {
        a = item[i]
        switch (a)
        {
            case "À": a='%C0';
            break;
            case "È": a='%C8';
            break;
            case "É": a='%C9';
            break;
            case "Ê": a='%CA';
            break;
            case "à": a='%E0';
            break;
            case "è": a='%E8';
            break;
            case "é": a='%E9';
            break;
            case "ê": a='%EA';
            break;
            case "ë": a='%EB';
            break;  
        }
        item[i] = a;
        console.log(item[i])
    }
    return item;
}
```

Anyone has found a successful way or has an idea (or a fix) why this is not working as intended?

Edit: `encodeURI` function does not support `é` and `è` characters (which are used a lot in French), those result as `Ã©` and `Ã¨`.

Comment: JavaScript has a built-in `encodeURI` function...

Comment: You're altering your data while you're traversing it. Try making a copy of the array, traversing that array, and then changing the respective values of `input`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas JavaScript's `encodeURI` function does not support `é` and `è` characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this OK?

```
var url_encode = function ( url ) {
    return url.split( '' ).map(function ( c ) {
        return /[ÀÈÉÊàèéêë]/.test( c ) ? '%' + c.charCodeAt( 0 ).toString( 16 ).toUpperCase() : c;
    }).join( '' );
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/v2He6/

(Note: You would need to [polyfill](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) `.map()` for IE8.)

Example:

```
url_encode( 'ABCÀDEFè' ) // "ABC%C0DEF%E8"
```

Comment: +5 billion points for the answer AND the IE notification. Thank you very much!